# Read custom header value from the response

Tags: spring-boot, header, aop

When I send request from the Soap UI under raw response tab I see the following result(find attachment). Now in AOP controller I want to read this header value which is marked as red. How it is possible? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the interesting question and the informative screenshot. I recommend to also add code, ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so the community can reproduce your situation, see what you tried so far and take it from there. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have standard aop JointPoint with @Around annotation on it like this: public Object restAOP(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

Comment: What was unclear about the term [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application to send soap requests I have `WebServiceTemplate`. I applied custom interceptor `WebServiceInterceptor` (which implements `ClientInterceptor` interface) on this web service template. In overridden `afterCompletion` method, which injects `MessageContext`, I was able to take this property from the `SaajMessageHeader`.

Here is what code looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebServiceConfig {
    
    @Bean(name = "myWSClient")
    public WebServiceTemplate myWSClient() throws Exception {
        WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate();
        
        ...

        WebServiceInterceptor[] interceptors = { new WebServiceInterceptor() };
        template.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return template;
    }
    
    
    private static class WebServiceInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

        @Override
        public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
            ...
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Exception ex) throws WebServiceClientException {
            try {
                SaajSoapMessage message = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();

                String []traceId = message.getSaajMessage().getMimeHeaders().getHeader("ITRACING_TRACE_ID");
                    if(traceId != null && traceId.length > 0){
                        process.setTraceId(traceId[0]);
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    
}
```